# GSON fromJson cannot deserialize -> strings containing foreign characters

Tags: android, json, json.net, gson, deserialization

I am sending string messages from a .NET application via `Bluetooth` to an Android Java Application.

Using `Newtonsoft JSON.NET` I serialize my messages in `JSON` and send them as-is to the Android application that attempts to convert them back with `Gson`.

This is my Message class:

```
public final class Message {
    private final String content;
    private final String address;
    private final long timeStamp;
    private boolean isRead;
    private boolean isSent;


    public Message(final String content, final String address, final long timeStamp,
               final boolean isSent, final boolean isRead) {
        this.content = content;
        this.address = address;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.isSent = isSent;
        this.isRead = isRead;
    }

    public final String getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }

    public final String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public final boolean isRead() {
        return this.isRead;
    }

    public final boolean isSent() {
        return this.isSent;
    }

    public final long getTimeStamp() {
        return this.timeStamp;
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing to fancy here. The .NET version of this class is rather similar, where instead of getters, there are `properties in pascal case` per as C# coding conventions.

I managed to solve the case-sensitiveness of Gson via 
`GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);`

Now my problem is straigforward : the following line will fail and throw a `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException` whenever I send a message containing "non-english" letters.

`final Message msg = gson.fromJson(message, Message.class);`

where message is a non-null not-empty String

Exemple : `la vie est très belle` (life is very beautiful)

The "intruder" here is the french accent `è`.

So here is the logcat of the stacktrace :

```
om.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 94
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:820)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
            at mackosoft.almightymessage.MainActivity$10.onNewMessageArrived(MainActivity.java:257)
            at mackosoft.almightymessage.bluetooth.module.events.BluetoothEventManager.notifyNewMessageArrived(BluetoothEventManager.java:77)
            at mackosoft.almightymessage.bluetooth.module.BluetoothManager$2.run(BluetoothManager.java:180)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 94
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1414)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:486)
            at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:418)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:190)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
            at mackosoft.almightymessage.MainActivity$10.onNewMessageArrived(MainActivity.java:257)
            at mackosoft.almightymessage.bluetooth.module.events.BluetoothEventManager.notifyNewMessageArrived(BluetoothEventManager.java:77)
            at mackosoft.almightymessage.bluetooth.module.BluetoothManager$2.run(BluetoothManager.java:180)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Note: I made sure all data transfered over Bluetooth back & forth between my .NET app and Android app is encoded in `UTF-8`.

Note bis : I tested multiple text messages. All of them worked except for the one with foreign letters !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

When looking at the JSON received by the Android application via the debugger on Android Studio, I could not see something wrong : all letters were correct, not strange or missing characters.

So I manually copied the JSON and created a quick `Java Application` with `Gson` to see if it would fail with the same kind of JSON content.

Guess what ? It worked ! So I thought, knowing that Java strings are by default always encoded in `UTF-8`, perhaps the JSON I actually send from the .NET application via `Bluetooth` is not ?

My `.NET Windows Store App` uses a `DataWriter` to write data over an `OutputStream`.
I was using `DataWriter.WriteString(string json)`. I changed it for `DataWriter.WriteBytes(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string json))` and it worked !

So that's it, problem solved !

It is strange that `DataWriter.WriteString` does not tell wich encoding it uses and if I can change it. The document only states : `Writes a string value to the output stream.`